# Dask efficient indexing of column-stored data as dask arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, dask

I'm trying to find an efficient way to index a dataset that is stored by columns in zarr arrays loaded with Dask (Python). I have to perform some operations on it, among which indexing all the columns according to another array (i.e. taking `column[ind] for column in columns`). I thought it was something trivial, yet I haven't find an efficient solution yet.

1. The first thing I tried was to simply use a dask dataframe, as that seems to be what I need. So I concatenated the columns in a 2d array and made a dataframe out of it. However, I often access the data per column, and I noticed that accessing a single column from the dataframe still loads all the data from disk (apparently all the columns in the 2d array are loaded by chunks and then only the selected one is kept). This is definitely a no-go for me. I have roughly 10000 columns, it is too inefficient.
2. The second thing I tried was to simply stick to a dict of dask arrays (columns). This is apparently fine for me, as I mainly have to perform operations on the arrays. Keep in mind that it is very important for me to have known chunk sizes because I often performs reshaping on the arrays. So, when indexing the arrays (like `df = {k : v[ind] for k, v in df.items()}`), I encounter the following issue:

   - if `ind` is a numpy array, the indexing operation simply blow up the RAM of my machine (64GB) despite the chunks being of the order of 20MB.
   - if `ind` is a dask array, I need to call `compute_chunk_sizes` on each array in order to calculate the resulting shape. However, this is extremely inefficient because dask is repeating the same chunk computation for every array in the dataset, while it could simply be done once for all.

In conclusion my question is: how would you tackle this problem? I'm open to consider other ways, keeping in mind that columnar-access is important for me.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it around by concatenating all the 1-d arrays into a 2-d array, then slicing over the first dimension, finally extracting the columns from such array. Accessing 1 array at time is still efficient, does not involve loading all data from disk.

Comment: nickname top amico mio :)